# How do I set the spectrum scope gain on the Icom IC-7300?

Tags: software-defined-radio, icom, icom-ic-7300, panadapter-and-waterfall

I have an IC-7300.

When observing weak signals, the *spectrum scope* has signal peaks that are way too small. Just now I was listening to a clearly audible CW signal that was easily heard but hardly moved the spectrum scope at all. I had to squint at it!

I'd like to set the ***gain*** of the 'signal scope' (***not the waterfall!)***.

I can set the reference level of the scope, but this only ***shifts*** the zero-value of both the spectrum and the waterfall up/down.
I can set the *Waterfall Peak Color Level*, but this only changes the gain of the color scale of the waterfall. It does not set the decibels per vertical line in the *scope itself*.

How do I set the gain of the spectrum scope?

[image: Compound image of two Icom 7300 screenshots, one with a small and the other with a large deflection of the spectrum scope.]

Comment: A forum like groups.io may be more appropriate for IC7300 questions, they have a large base of 7300 users. [link](https://groups.io/g/ic-7300)

Answer (score 2):

To access "Spectrum Scope" Settings Menu : (press and hold) `EXPD / SET`.  The manual entry on this page is on page 71 (https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1106166/Icom-Ic-7300.html?page=71#manual)

It does not appear to have a gain adjustment.